# JavaFX How to get data of selected row from Tableview

Tags: java, tableview

I would like to get data from one selected row

I have this little code

```
Stlpce aktualne = (Stlpce) tableview_objednavka.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
    double aktcena = aktualne.getCena();
```

But When I run the app I get this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel$5 cannot be cast to sample.Stlpce
```

I use scene builder for create TableView.

Can you help me?

This is solved - the problem was, that I have `getSelectedItems();` instead of `getSelectedItem();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is clear in its meaning:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html

The method call you make (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.TableViewSelectionModel.html#getSelectedItems--) returns a reference to an

```
ObvservableList<T>
```

Object, which Stlpe does not implement/extend and therefore a Stlpe reference cannot point to such an Object.

Is the Stlpe class the Type class of your ObservableList?  If so, maybe you need to find the Stlpe Object in your list:

```
if (returnedList.size() > 0) {
    Stlpe item = returnedList.get(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only care about which row is selected, assuming you have a TableView, you can simply use:

> List selected = selectionModel.getSelectedItems();

or if your table only allows single row selection:

> SomeObject selected = selectionModel.getSelectedItem();
>
> System.out.println(selected.getName());

Try it 100% working...

or try this for better understand [Get row data from TableView](http://java-buddy.blogspot.in/2013/03/javafx-get-row-data-from-tableview.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your declaration the `TableView`  should be casted to your object
eg: `TableView <Stlpce> tableview_objednavka;`